# Как исправить проблему с попапом на слайдере slick

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Проблема заключается в следующем: есть слайдер slick , на слайды установлен попап magnific на активный слайд, при нажатии на не активный слайд - он не открывается в попапе, а перелистывается и становится активным( принимает класс .slick-active), но когда на этот уже активный слайд происходит нажатие - то попап не выскакивает. То есть класс .slick-active дается этому слайду на ходу, и скрипт magnific не успевает определить что этот класс активный. Как решить эту проблему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: готовое же есть : https://codepen.io/garik911/pen/orXYpy

Comment: пользуйтесь поиском : [поиск по codepen](https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=slick%20%2B%20lightbox&page=1&order=popularity&depth=everything)

Comment: @MaximLensky первый вариант не рабочий для моей ситуации. имеет такую же проблему

Comment: а этот ? https://codepen.io/jasanka/pen/wRvdpd?editors=1000

Comment: @MaximLensky собственно тоже. срабатывают попапы на всех слайдах